# Can't z.infer<> in a generic typescript parameter when schema contains a union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

So I'm trying to make a helper that will allow me to easily create empty/initial form values from a zod schema that will validate the whole/complete form. In other words I want the schema to require every field to be populated, but initial values might be nullable...

Anyway I am confused by an issue demonstrated in [this sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=28&pln=30&pc=35#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgLABQlMAnmAKZwDyARgFYDqwMAFgKoA7YBAFwAvIkpxpcYvXpgAXJIoy1cAK5CRy-AEN8cAD4EW5VTLSUrVCgGMRAZ3iO7PeiD3iUAOgjt6OxgACgQpGTkFZWQ-AKDQ8PVNbQFon3oBDRBggG19fAAaU3wAXQBKRPQKijRqykp6AA9IWDhaBjgAEXkwACUFABs9O3oAHgAVIr4APnFw8bgmmAziRy69ZbgAfjg+RcblgVX1zZ295UyBgbhFSoWllbX-NkD4Sukz-cPj59e4d5kOzCFiS0hyAGk4MBRABreg0CCYODjErKSEPI5rOEIpF7AFJHbdBT9MBDEYTCElKaU2b49TKcaUr6POC-ILbLo9ElksaM8FUxBwHIw5TOKDQgDmqLgl2uaFpINBagZTJMsrpGDpyiJfUGw15RSQwtFMHFAilFw0V3QCqSyj49VsmC0QWEok8cNYbFGnWZmLgAAU9LBgHoBqMYtDMPQoKMAMrTaZFON+44xABaJHGdHoAEEBDRpsFXO5PMo40UAG7asppTPEbMMH1cvXkyMCaOxhNFTqJlQAen7WBdMDdcA99C9PtTayDIbDEZ8UZjo3a9ERcBLHj0ieTM989cbeYLRa3ZbgFbg1a6tYPWZzzeJrbG7c78aTXT7wLUUHoMA0UCiGeXh6GsGb3k2Orcvqi7Ll2H69tM1iOg4AjOKy7DeBOXrFm426GpUkRKCoSpaG6ugGJUNi1D4YDBo49ChLUjpAA)

With the following code:

```
const schema = z.object({
    deep: z.object({
        union: z.enum(['a', 'b'])
    })
})

function makeObj<D extends Partial<z.infer<typeof schema>>, S extends z.ZodTypeAny>(schema: S, v: D): z.ZodType<DeepReplace<z.infer<S>, D>> {
    return schema as z.ZodType<DeepReplace<z.infer<S>, D>>
}

const obj = makeObj(schema, {
    deep: {
        union: 'a'
    }
}).parse({})
```

`obj` is correctly typed:

```
const obj: {
    deep: {
        union: "a";
    };
}
```

[image]

But if I replace the function declaration with this line:

```
function makeObj<D extends Partial<z.infer<S>>, S extends z.ZodTypeAny>(schema: S, v: D): z.ZodType<DeepReplace<z.infer<S>, D>> {
    return schema as z.ZodType<DeepReplace<z.infer<S>, D>>
}
const obj = makeObj(schema, {
    deep: {
        union: 'a'
    }
}).parse({})
```

Now type inference is broken:

```
const obj: {
    deep: {
        union: null;
    } | {
        union: "a" | "b";
    };
}
```

[image]

Unless, I have found I put "as const" on the second argument:

```
const obj = makeObj(schema, {
    deep: {
        union: 'a'
    }
} as const).parse({})
```

- It appears that this is only a problem when union types are involved
- I'd love not to have to bother with the `as const` everywhere.
- And mostly I'd like to understand why using z.infer<> is the source of the issue!

Thanks!

-Morgan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your `DeepReplace` type in conjunction with the `Partial` you're wrapping the `z.infer<typeof S>` with. The `Partial` adds an `| undefined` to each value in the inferred type and `DeepReplace` is a [distributed conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) so it will map `DeepReplace` onto first the key (which is where the `deep: "a" | "b"` comes from) and then the `undefined` which is where the `|` null comes from.

[Playground with `null` replaced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgEpYDYCGAxsADwAqANHAKoB8cAvALABQcc5coMwAdgBMAzugK84AflrcQvQSLRjUUmnABccAOQBBTerYcOXHv2FwIAIwBWwIvAOGOKmXLOWbduA8dO4Ab28fDgBtAGk4AEs+OABrYEQIADNOAF0NcJN5WPik6UCg3wwsXDBCEgowlOoaSoZ8go1ySpdTEXdbeCkinHxiMibQqv84YJiNIRgoKIBzNK0AIT0AXzr2AqDG5oAfLQBhTXqOJa81jfRMHtK+imo-EbG4Cam+WY1NNGXVs5o2NijeKCJPpwACSADEIBB-A4BBcNAFTnACBo+ABXAC2FmAUDgOyeMwA3A4lmwSaw-nwAUCSKD5gQcQiOLCsCiMVioETWGS2EgUAgAIxMc7FXrlcGQ6ggulQOicgD0csMAD0JL9WLzUDAAExC7olMpkAAK9JgEQIeFI4ogdEl0tlbAVyokQA) so you can see where the null comes from. It's still a little hard to see what's going on even in this reduced example, but another reason I'm convinced it's the `Partial` + the distributed conditional type is because adding `as const` fixes the issue.

When you added `as const` the inferred type for `D` becomes exactly the value you passed in and the `Partial` is unwrapped because the exact type is known which means there are no `| undefined`s tacked on.

I'm not 100% sure what you want the behavior of your `DeepReplace` type to be, but you can replace some of the `null`'s with `nevers` to prune the conditional distributions that you don't want. For example,

```js
export type DeepReplace<T, U> =
  T extends Date ? U extends Date ? U : never :
    T extends object 
      ? U extends object 
        ? {
          [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U 
            ? DeepReplace<T[K], U[K]> 
            : T[K] extends object ? DeepReplace<T[K], { [k: string]: null }> 
              : T[K] | null
        } 
        : never
      : U
```

This doesn't have the `| union: null` for the case you described. The inner `T[K] | null` and `DeepReplace<T[K], { [k: string]: null }>` I left alone because I'm not sure what they're meant to be doing, but you could consider replacing those arms with `never`.